# concurrently reading large datasets from JDBC (MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, performance, jdbc, concurrency

I need to read large results of sql queries concurrently. I do not know the queries in advance or the result set size, but I expect it to be large (up usually around 10^5 or 10^6 but some may get up toup to 10^8 maybe even 10^9) but. I do not really care how I actually go about querying the database so long as the combined result of the concurrent reading is logically equivalent to just executing the original query directly. I can transform the query into multiple queries if needed, provided I can do it in a generic way that is agnostic about the original query. What I really need to optimize is the total processing time. So sequentially iterating through a single result set in the master and just distributing the rows to the workers for is also option, but I would like to know how that compares to the alternatives.

Comment: How large is large?  You should specify some sort of estimate. Are we talking hundreds, thousands, millions?

Comment: Basically I am lookind for the fastest way to push data from a single mysql server through a cluster of workers. If I undertsand the answer to the referenced question then the suggested approach is to read the data sequatially client side and mutiplex to the workers asynchronously. I was starting to suspect that might be the way to go as I was looking in the problem more.